# Show dropdown in cell of kendo grid in template

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid working fine but i want to display the drop down in all cell of a column ie "Security Action" column cell. whether u r editing or not editing so the user know that this is dropdown in that cell.I dont want like that when click in cell a  drop down appear like mention in [this](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/editing-custom.html) demo site of kendo.

My code is given below

> HTML:

```
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="clientsDb">
    <div id="grid" style="top:0px;width:100%;height: 380px">
    </div>              
    </div>
```

> CSS:

```
<style scoped>
#clientsDb {
     width: 1400px;
         height: 310px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 0 4px 0 4px;
     background: url('../kendo/content/web/grid/clientsDb.png') no-repeat 0 0;
      }
</style>
```

> JS:

```
 <script>
        function kendoGridExecute(data){
        $(document).ready(function() {

                                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                                        dataSource: {
                                            data: data.items,
                                            autoSync: true,
                                            schema: {
                                                model: {
                                                  fields: {
                                                        Type: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                                        Penalty:{ editable: false, nullable: true },
                                                        Init_r:{ editable: false, nullable: true },
                                                        Opt_r:{ editable: false, nullable: true },
                                                        Change_r:{editable: false, nullable: true},     
                                                        Action:{defaultValue : {text: "No Action", value: "No Action" } }                               
                                                        }
                                                }
                                            }

                                        },
                                        groupable: true,
                                        sortable: true,
                                        scrollable: true,
                                        filterable: true,
                                        editable : true,

                                        columns: [ {
                                                field : "Type",
                                                width : 90,
                                                title : "Type"                                      
                                            } , {
                                                field : "Penalty",
                                                width : 120,
                                                title : "Penalty"

                                            } , {
                                                width : 50,
                                                field : "Bmk",
                                                title : "Abs. Bmk",
                                                template:"<input class='k-textbox' data-bind='value: Bmk' style='width:50px'>"     
                                            } , {
                                                width : 50,
                                                field : "Init_r",
                                                title : "Rel. Init"
                                            } , {
                                                width : 50,
                                                field : "Opt_r",
                                                title : "Rel. Opt"
                                            } , {
                                                title : "Rel. Chg",
                                                field : "Change_r",
                                                width : 50
                                            },{
                                                title : "Min",
                                                field : "Min",
                                                width: 50,
                                                template:"<input class='k-textbox' data-bind='value: Min' style='width:50px'>" 
                                            },{
                                                title : "Max",
                                                field : "Max",
                                                width : 50,
                                                template:"<input class='k-textbox' data-bind='value: Max' style='width:50px'>" 
                                            },{
                                                field : "Scale",
                                                title : "Scale",
                                                width : 50,
                                                template:"<input class='k-textbox' data-bind='value: Scale' style='width:50px'>" 
                                            },
                                            {
                                                field : "Init",
                                                title : "Abs. Init",
                                                width : 50
                                            },
                                            {
                                                field : "Opt",
                                                title : "Abs. Opt",
                                                width : 50
                                            },
                                            {
                                                field : "Action",
                                                title : "Security Action",
                                                width : 100,
                                                editor: securityActionDropDownEditor,
                                                template: "#=Action#" 
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        batch: true,
                                        dataBound: function() {
                                            var rows = this.tbody.children();
                                            var dataItems = this.dataSource.view();
                                                for (var i = 0; i < dataItems.length; i++)  {
                                                  kendo.bind(rows[i], dataItems[i]);
                                                }
                                            }


                                    });
                                });


                            }
                            function securityActionDropDownEditor(container, options) {

                                $('<input required data-text-field="text" data-value-field="value" data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
                                    .appendTo(container)
                                    .kendoDropDownList({
                                                dataSource: [ 
                                                              { text: "No Action", value: "No Action" },
                                                              { text: "DNS", value: "DNS" },
                                                              { text: "DNB", value: "DNB" },
                                                              { text: "DNT", value: "DNT" }
                                                 ],
                                                 autoBind: false,
                                                 index:0
                                    });
                                console.log(options);
                                console.log(options.field);
                            }
                            </script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it with client template and some custom logic to initialize the DropDownLists when the dataBound event of the Grid occurs.

Let's say you have the following tempalte for the column:

```
template: "<input value='#= PositionID #' data-bind='value:PositionID' data-role='dropdownlist' data-source='options' data-text-field='Text' data-value-field='Value' />"
```

where options is a global variable that contains the collection that you want to use as dataSource

```
 var options = [{Text:"T1",Value:"V1"}...]
```

Then on the [dataBound](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#events-dataBound) event of the Grid you can bind that DropDownList to the underling model for that row like this:

```
function onGridDataBound() {
    var grid = this;
    this.tbody.find('tr').each(function () {
        var item = grid.dataItem(this);
        kendo.bind(this, item);
    })
}
```

Comment: data-source='options' is not working neither data-source=' "+options+" ' is working at all why ???

Comment: here is a problem please help me out when ever the combo value change the databound event call and it iterate all the rows as define in function which is producing performance issue.

Comment: Great Answer. Would you know how to handle the change event? I can get it to fire, but I am failing when trying to pass `RowId` and `dropdownId`. I've tried adding this call. `onchange='GridDDLChange(#=RowId#,#=DDLId#)'` It works without the parameters but somehow I am not passing them correctly.

Comment: Not sure but try to put those inside quotes so they can be considered strings. onchange='GridDDLChange(\"#=RowId#\",\"#=DDLId#\")'

Anyway there are far more convenient ways to use delegated events.

Comment: Ah Genius! It worked but it passes previous `ddlID` not what it was changed to. Guess that's a result of your "more convenient ways to do this" response. Thanks much!

Comment: For anyone else stumpling upon my problem above...I solved it by changing the parameter to `this`. So the call looks like  `onchange='GridDDLChange(\"#=AcctName#\",this)`. Call .value on the second parameter in your function to get the Id. `function GridDDLChange(AcctName, SportId)....SportId.value`